# Find partial derivatives for $\sqrt[3]{(x^3 + y^3)}$ at the point $(0,0)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

For the function: $\sqrt[3]{(x^3 + y^3)}$ I'm requested to find both partial derivatives at the point $(0,0)$. I believe this is a problem that uses the limit definition of a partial derivative, however I always get 0 as an answer, which is incorrect. Can someone help me to sort this out?

Comment: What did you do, then?

Comment: I performed the partial derivatives without the limit definition, I always get 0/0

Comment: @OscarAguilar As a suggestion, for the next time you should add more detail about your work and effort in order to fullfil the standard for a "good question" and help us to give you some useful advice to conclude that. Bye

Comment: I did say so, for an answer that fulfills the standard of "good answer" see Gio's. Bye :)

Comment: @OscarAguilar Nothing personal from my side, you are free to choose the best answer according to your preference, mine was a suggestion to avoid downvotes or closure to your questions. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to0} \frac{f((0,0)+t(1,0))-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{t^3}}{t}=\lim_{t\to0} \frac{t}{t}=1$. It is analogous for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

By the definition we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{h^3}}{h}$$

and similarly for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$.

Comment: Correct. But in both cases the limit is 0, isn't?

Comment: What about $\sqrt[3]{h^3}$?